# Does Parse.com support prompting Users to agree to terms & privacy policy agreements

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfloginviewcontroller

I'm using PFSignUpViewController and PFLogInViewController to prompt users to create accounts and login.

How can I prompt users to agree to some "disclaimers": my app's terms & conditions and a privacy policy? I haven't found an example on parse.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse doesn't offer direct support, but both the login and signup views controllers offer the ability to add custom subviews to their views which could contain text or buttons and they both also offer a number of delegate callbacks which could be used to trigger display. You can also simply display the 'alert' when you show the login or signup view in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the length of text in my app's Terms I've decided to leave Parse.com login/signup view controllers untouched.

Instead, I display my terms in their own view controller with accept/decline buttons. If the user accepts then I route to the standard Parse login/signup view controllers.

If Parse extend their authentication process, with 2-factor authentication for example, then I'll be able to drop this into my app.

I think adding a "terms" control as one might do for a web page doesn't work well for a mobile UI where space and user focus are much tighter.

The post by @Wain is still correct.